# Aggregate attribute value of polygon within geometry of another polygon layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, aggregate, qgis-expression

[image: 1]

I have two layers, both polygons.

One layer includes watersheds as polygons, each watershed is it's own attribute row. The second layer is a segmented stream network, each segment is it's own attribute row.

I want to take the mean value, let's say there's an attribute called "blades of grass", of all of the stream network segments that lie within the watershed boundary.

I was trying to add a new attribute column to the watersheds layer, then use field calculator.

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'Stream',
aggregate:='mean',
expression:= "bladesgrass",
filter:=contains(@watershed, $geometry)
 )
```

I am not sure how can I choose the attribute column from the streams layer "blades of grass" to run the expression on that attribute WITHIN the specific watershed boundary. I am also showing the image because some of the segments lie within multiple watersheds. I do not know what to put in the expression part of `aggregate()` or if I will have issues because some of the segments lie within multiple watersheds.

Comment: If you run an intersect of your segments with the watersheds that will split the segments at watershed boundaries and attribute them with the watershed they are in.  If you can't simple recalculate your bladesgrass or other values you will have to find some other way to apportion them perhaps using lengths. In any case after you can export the data to a spreadsheet and run a pivot on your line data to get your values and then join that back to your watersheds.  You might also look at the Overlap Analysis tool in the Vector Analysis group.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the "join attributes by location (summary)" tool. I was able to get output that seemed reasonable. Does that tool seem appropriate given the question I have? I am fairly new to QGIS, so I am not sure if that method is a red flag

Comment: Use `geometry(@parent)` instead `@watershed`